# Appium Android Python - find element using text attribute

Tags: python, android, appium-android

I am trying to find an element using driver.find_element_by_name("Now Playing"), but its throwing exception. 
Is there a way to find an element by an attribute value? In my case the attribute is 'text' and value is 'Now Playing'.

The following is the XML source of the screen. Precisely, I am trying to select on the third tab of within 'Albums','Artists','Now Playing'.

Thanks a lot for your time and help.

## XML contents for the tabs:

```
        <android.widget.LinearLayout index="2" package="com.nmp.simp.phone" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" text="" resource-id="com.nmp.simp.phone:id/tab_control" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,1776][1080,1920]" displayed="true">
          <android.widget.LinearLayout index="0" package="com.nmp.simp.phone" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" text="" resource-id="com.nmp.simp.phone:id/bg_tab" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,1776][360,1920]" displayed="true">
            <android.widget.ImageView index="0" package="com.nmp.simp.phone" class="android.widget.ImageView" text="" resource-id="com.nmp.simp.phone:id/icon" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="true" bounds="[127,1778][232,1883]" displayed="true" />
            <android.widget.TextView index="1" package="com.nmp.simp.phone" class="android.widget.TextView" text="Albums" resource-id="com.nmp.simp.phone:id/text" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[135,1874][225,1911]" displayed="true" />
          </android.widget.LinearLayout>
          <android.widget.LinearLayout index="1" package="com.nmp.simp.phone" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" text="" resource-id="com.nmp.simp.phone:id/bg_tab" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[360,1776][720,1920]" displayed="true">
            <android.widget.ImageView index="0" package="com.nmp.simp.phone" class="android.widget.ImageView" text="" resource-id="com.nmp.simp.phone:id/icon" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[487,1778][592,1883]" displayed="true" />
            <android.widget.TextView index="1" package="com.nmp.simp.phone" class="android.widget.TextView" text="Artists" resource-id="com.nmp.simp.phone:id/text" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[504,1874][576,1911]" displayed="true" />
          </android.widget.LinearLayout>
          <android.widget.LinearLayout index="2" package="com.nmp.simp.phone" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" text="" resource-id="com.nmp.simp.phone:id/bg_tab" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[720,1776][1080,1920]" displayed="true">
            <android.widget.TextView index="0" package="com.nmp.simp.phone" class="android.widget.TextView" text="Now Playing" resource-id="com.nmp.simp.phone:id/text" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[826,1874][974,1911]" displayed="true" />
            <android.widget.ImageView index="1" package="com.nmp.simp.phone" class="android.widget.ImageView" text="" resource-id="com.nmp.simp.phone:id/icon" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[847,1778][952,1883]" displayed="true" />
          </android.widget.LinearLayout>
        </android.widget.LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could locate the element with the text attribute by following the below approach:

1. Search on all elements with the class name:

   elements_list = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("android.widget.TextView")
2. Iterate through the list of elements and find the element that has 'Now Playing' in the 'text' attribute. If found invoke click() on the element.

   for element in ui_elements:
          if 'Now Playing' in str(element.get_attribute("text")):
              element.click()

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this too and Rak's answer worked for me.

```
messages = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('android.widget.TextView')

for i in messages:
    if 'text you are looking for' in i.text:
        i.click()
```